# Can I manage the Heroku Scheduler from the CLI?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Is there a way I can access and manage the Heroku Scheduler through the CLI (I want to manage it through a bash script)? The only way I know about right now is through the UI on the Heroku site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduling-jobs) tasks can be managed through the web dashboard. The only CLI command mentioned there is

```
heroku addons:open scheduler
```

to open the web dashboard. The [platform API documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) doesn't mention the scheduler at all.

I believe the only way to manage tasks is through the web dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but things have changed recently.

I created an Heroku add-on named Schedulerctl.

This add-on enables you to create and manage your Heroku Scheduler jobs using the Heroku CLI (as well as a REST API).

Examples:

`heroku jobs --app example`

`heroku jobs:add -a example --command "sleep 60" --frequency "*/10 * * * *" --dynoSize Standard-1X`

`heroku jobs:update 123456789 -a example -c "sleep 60" -f "0 0 * * *" -d Standard-2X`

`heroku jobs:remove 123456789 -a example`

To use this, install the Schedulerctl add-on on your Heroku app and install the Schedulerctl Heroku CLI plugin by running the command `$ heroku plugins:install schedulerctl`.

More information can be found at https://documentation.schedulerctl.com.

Comment: Hey Oscar, this looks exactly like what I need but the link seems broken. I see you have a similar project on your GitHub that works with the advanced scheduler, but is this (the one that works with the basic scheduler) not being maintained anymore?

Comment: Hi Xoel, just noticed your comment. Unfortunately this no longer works and will never work again in the future as it was not allowed by Salesforce.